# Changing control background color in javascript - but how to reset color when validation passses before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using the following code to change the background color of all invalid controls on a page. However, when the background color changes and a user enters the correct value for the field, I want the background to reset to the original color for the now valid field before the page is submitted? I am using RequiredFieldValidators for all controls and all controls have the same validation group (except for 1 control which has both the RequiredFieldValidator and the RegularExpressionValidator. thanks!

```
  function changeColor()
         {
             Page_ClientValidate();
             var i;
             var ctrl;
             var prevColor;
             for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
               ctrl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
               prevColor = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).style.backgroundColor;
               if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid)
                    ctrl.style.backgroundColor = '#FFAAAA';
               else
                   ctrl.style.backgroundColor = prevColor; 

              }
         }
```

Here is how the above javascript is called:

```
<asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Press btn" 
                 ID="SaveButton" 
                 runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl="~/css/btnSave.png" 
                 OnClick="btpress_Click" 
                 OnClientClick="javascript:return changeColor();"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the JavaScript that you posted doesn't work?  Have you tried passing in "this" into changeColor()?

For example, OnClientClick="javascript:return changeColor(this);"

This way you should have a reference back to the control which then you should be able to manipulate its CSS properties.  I don't have the time at the moment to simulate this problem, but this was something I thought of off the top of my head.

Comment: The Javascript works perfectly! However, when the javascript changes the color of the control for which the validation fails, I want the color to reset to the original color when the validation for the control passes (even before the form is submitted).

Comment: The script does work and it is great. However I agree with Mike that a solution of restoring the original colors of controls is definitely a plus